# Symfony deploying issue

Tags: symfony1

I have some problem while configuring symfony project on the production server. When I run the command doctrine --build --all --and-load it gives me error in the production environment:

```
   
>> doctrine  Dropping "doctrine" database
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  dbname in /var/www/sf_project/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1472

Notice: Undefined index:  dbname in /var/www/sf_project/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1472
>> doctrine  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an erro...e right syntax to use near '' at line 1. Failing Query: "DROP DATABASE "
>> doctrine  Creating "dev" environment "doctrine" database
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  dbname in /var/www/sf_project/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1439
```

However after the error it creates the table successfully. But if I run the command second times it fails partially while crating the tables.

I have changed my database.yml configuration properly for the production environment. here it is:

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sf_project
      port: 3306
      username: root
      password: mainserver
```

Its working right in the local environment though.
Can some one shed some light on it ?

**Editing note: added the content of '/cache//prod/config/config_databases.yml.php' file as 'xzyfer' suggested.**

Here's the content :

```
return array(
'doctrine' => new sfDoctrineDatabase(array (
  'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=sf_project',
  'port' => 3306,
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => 'mainserver',
  'name' => 'doctrine',
)),);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
./symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load --env=prod
```

Comment: @xzyfer: Thanks it has removed that undefined index error message. But there's another SQL error showing while droping and creating the database:
`> doctrine  Dropping "doctrine" database
>> doctrine  SQLSTATE[42000]: Sytax error or access violtion: 1064 You hve an error in you...n for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1. Failing Query: "DROP DATABASE "
>> doctrine  Creating "prod" environment "doctrine" database
>> doctrine  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax eror or access violtion: 1064 You have an error in you...for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1. Failing Query: "CREATE DATABASE "`

Comment: Have you cleared your cache? The error is essentially saying you have given a dns name in your database.yml try ./symfony cc first

Comment: @xzyfer: my databases.yml looks as I mentioned in the post. And I have used ./symfony cc ! Can you explain a bit more? 

@cuhuak: yes my cache is writable ! I have executed ./symfony project:permissions !

Comment: @medhad, could you add the contents of the following file to you question. <project_root>/cache/<app_name>/prod/config/config_databases.yml.php

Comment: @xzyfer: I just added the content of that file from cache directory. You'll find it at the bottom of the question !

Comment: @medhad, this might be trivial but try removing the space from `mysql:host=localhost; dbname=sf_project` otherwise I can't see an issue.

Comment: @xzyfer: thanks a lot! removing the space on that line inside database.yml solved the issue! :)